# Alternative to global events

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I am developing a FOSS service bus.

One of the things developers will need is to hook into certain events that take place.  Currently I have a static `ServiceBusEvents` class that exposes all of the possible events that may be of interest, e.g.:

```
public static event BeforeEnqueueMessageDelegate BeforeEnqueueMessage = delegate { };
public static event BeforeDequeueMessageDelegate BeforeDequeueMessage = delegate { };
public static event AfterEnqueueMessageDelegate AfterEnqueueMessage = delegate { };
public static event AfterDequeueMessageDelegate AfterDequeueMessage = delegate { };
```

There are a finite number of events but I don't know whether this is the best way to go.

Is there a 'cleaner' way to get the same thing done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have 1 event and make the first parameter the eventname. That will make your library future proof, as a new event wont alter the existing interface.
The disadvantage is that any parameter would need to be casted before it could be used.
(Alternatively, use a base class for the event and people can switch on the type of that instead)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so there doesn't appear to any strong objection to this or there is no real 'cleaner' way :)

Thanks for your input Cine.

Comment: Please use the commenting system instead of adding answers.